How to add a Firebase project to an existing GCP project? (using terraform)
When I tried to add Firebase to an existing project with Terraform, I got the following error:

Error creating Project: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission

I think the account may lack permissions on my project but I don't know what I'm missing.
Currently, I have the following permissions, but I have not been able to check the organizational policy.

roles/firebase.admin
roles/owner

I would like to know what might be missing. Also, these are things I have come across while using terraform.
Regarding Firebase, I tried adding Viewer and Develop Admin permissions, but it didn't work.
I added some permissions to my user account.
